# Wordpress Bug In Google search : showing already deleted malware directory

Tags: wordpress

Hope you doing well.
Recently I've built a site on a managed wp hosting called easywp. The site was attacked by malware. Securi scan report was showing up..
I deleted all the files except wp-content and uploaded a fresh wordpress through sftp server.I didn't make any changes of the database..
After this, The securi scan shows the malware is removed.. But when i search for my domain name on google(attachment) please see the .... /advertisel, which is already deleted! or even i write it on twitter for sharing the site, the information show below the link is the injected link..
I'm unable to configure where from the code is coming.Can anyone help me to find it out?
Thank you! [image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to resubmit the site maps or update Google's crawling of your website. There are plenty of resources online to assist you with the how to for this process.